# miller effect - What circuits have miller effect?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, bjt, fet

I have an exam tomorrow and I have a theoretical question. Just have Miller effect common source (FET) / common emitter (BJT)? Or common drain (FET) / common collector (BJT) also have? Is there some kind of circuit I did not mention that has Miller effect?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_effect <-- clearly explains how the Miller effect is derived and that it applies to *amplifieres*, not to specific types of semiconductor devices.

Comment: @MarcusMüller But could you answer the question? It is a very concrete question. It seems to me to have heard that the miller effect only existed on the common source or common emitter amplifiers. But does it occur in common drain or common sink?

Comment: This is an extremely vague question because there are multiple (amplifier) circuits that the Miller Effect applies to. For example, the two-stage operational amplifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Miller effect only occurs on amplifiers. Inverting amplifiers to be specific.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_effect

Common collector transistor circuit has a gain of 1, ie it does not amplify. In this case, Cgd or Cbc is a simple capacitor, and it is not multiplied by Miller effect.

Common emitter amplifier circuit has negative gain, and thus Miller effect applies to Cbc/Cgd.